# c# wpf mvvm DataGrid Hyperlink to Path

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I want to create a `DataGrid` to show informations I read from a `LogFile`. The `DataGrid` displays the occured errors, found in `LogFiles`. Reading them and creating Objects for each error is no problem.

Now I need to add the `LogFile` path to the `DataGrid` and make it clickable. So when you click on the path the `LogFile` should open. Im using `mvvm` pattern, so no code in code-behind allowed.

I found 2 different ideas to my problem but none of them solved it:

First one with an `TemplateColumn`:

```
<DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
         VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
         Margin="10"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Errors}"
         SelectionMode="Single"
         SelectedItem="{Binding Mode=OneWayToSource, Path=SelectedError}"
         AutoGenerateColumns="False"
         IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Path=Data.Texts[FaultyFileCaption], Source={StaticResource DataContextProxy}}" Binding="{Binding Path=FaultyFile}" Width="Auto"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Path=Data.Texts[LanguageCaption], Source={StaticResource DataContextProxy}}" Binding="{Binding Path=Language}" Width="Auto"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Path=Data.Texts[KindCaption], Source={StaticResource DataContextProxy}}" Binding="{Binding Path=Type}" Width="Auto"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Path=Data.Texts[ErrorCodeCaption], Source={StaticResource DataContextProxy}}" Binding="{Binding Path=ErrorCode}" Width="Auto"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Path=Data.Texts[SourcePathCaption], Source={StaticResource DataContextProxy}}" Binding="{Binding Path=SourcePath}" Width="Auto"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{Binding Path=Data.Texts[LogFilePath], Source={StaticResource DataContextProxy}}" Width="Auto">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock>
                        <Hyperlink Command="{Binding ElementName=ErrorDataGrid, Path=Data.CmdLogFilePathClick, Source={StaticResource DataContextProxy}}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LogFilePath}"/>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

and the second one using an `HyperlinkColumn`:

```
<DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
         VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
         Margin="10"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Errors}"
         SelectionMode="Single"
         SelectedItem="{Binding Mode=OneWayToSource, Path=SelectedError}"
         AutoGenerateColumns="False"
         IsReadOnly="True"
         Name="ErrorDataGrid">

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Path=Data.Texts[FaultyFileCaption], Source={StaticResource DataContextProxy}}" Binding="{Binding Path=FaultyFile}" Width="Auto"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Path=Data.Texts[LanguageCaption], Source={StaticResource DataContextProxy}}" Binding="{Binding Path=Language}" Width="Auto"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Path=Data.Texts[KindCaption], Source={StaticResource DataContextProxy}}" Binding="{Binding Path=Type}" Width="Auto"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Path=Data.Texts[ErrorCodeCaption], Source={StaticResource DataContextProxy}}" Binding="{Binding Path=ErrorCode}" Width="Auto"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Path=Data.Texts[SourcePathCaption], Source={StaticResource DataContextProxy}}" Binding="{Binding Path=SourcePath}" Width="Auto"/>
        <DataGridHyperlink Header="{Binding Path=Data.Texts[LogFilePath], Source={StaticResource DataContextProxy}}" Binding="{Binding Path=LogFilePath}" Width="Auto">
            <DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style>
                    <EventSetter Event="Hyperlink.Click" Handler="{Binding Path=Data.DG_Hyperlink_Click, Source={StaticResource DataContextProxy}}"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

In both cases my Command or Handler does only open the file at the given path.

I hope you understand my problem and many thanks for any help I can get :)

Comment: "using mvvm pattern, so no code in code-behind allowed", where did you read that?

Comment: MVVM is a pattern that removes the business logic from the markup/GUI

Comment: Well my boss told me not to write Code in code-behind.
Only constructor allowed.

Comment: How are you trying to open the logfile? Does the code in the command execute?

Comment: Im not reaching the Code in my command. with the templateColumn i get an XamlParseException and with the HyperlinkColumn nothing happens when clicking the link. Not even an excpetion is thrown

Comment: I don't think the EventSetter does exactly what you think it does. Check [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/zorgoban/how-to-hook-an-event-to-a-command-in-xaml-with-eventcommandsetter/)

Answer (score 0):

In your first approach you have to do the Command-Binding like:

```
Command="{Binding DataContext.CmdLogFilePathClick, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"
```

If your `DataGrid` is located in a `UserControl` and not a `Window` change it to:

```
Command="{Binding DataContext.CmdLogFilePathClick, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"
```

Comment: Why do i Need this RealtiveSource and how does it works?

Comment: With the `RelativeSource` you can tell your `Command` where it should search it's DataContext.   Check if this solution works for you.

Comment: I got it working but like this:
`Command="{Binding Path=Data.CmdLogFilePathClick, Source={StaticResource DataContextProxy}}"`

Comment: And the DataContextProxy directs to your DataContext, right? Than it's the same as a relativesource to your container which holds the datacontext

Comment: yes the DataContextProxy directs to my DataContext. Thanks for your help :)